# Python Can't extract data from string search in 2 files?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I use this code to search and compare string in 2 files

```
fsig = open('file1.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8")
fresult = open('file2.txt', 'r' , encoding="utf8")
node = {}

for line in fsig:
    L = line.split()
    if(L[0] == 'v'):
        node[L[2]] = int(L[1])

extracted = {}

for line in fresult:
    L = line.split()
    if(L!=[]):

        if(L[0] == 'v' and L[2] not in extracted):
            extracted[L[2]] = node[L[2]]

print(node)
print(extracted)
```

I have string in 2 file like this.

file 1

```
v 0 .
v 1 nn
v 2 ht
v 3 [root]
e 1 0 punctuation
e 3 1 root
e 3 2 root
```

file 2

```
t # 17
v 0 ht
v 1 [root]
e 1 0 root
t # 7
v 0 nn
t # 8
v 0 [root]
t # 5
v 0 ht
t # 6
v 0 .
```

when I run program it show output like this.

```
{'[root]': 3, 'ht': 2, '.': 0, 'nn': 1}
{'nn': 1, 'ht': 2, '.': 0, '[root]': 3}
```

If I change data file 2 like this

```
 t # 52

v 0 jj

v 1 prp$

v 2 nn

v 3 nnp

v 4 vbz

v 5 .

v 6 prp

v 7 vbp

v 8 [root]

v 9 ht

e 2 0 adjectival

e 2 1 possession

e 4 2 direct

e 4 3 nominal

e 7 4 clausal

e 7 5 punctuation

e 7 6 nominal

e 8 7 root

e 8 9 root

e 9 9 null


t # 53

v 0 prp$

v 1 nn

v 2 nnp

v 3 vbz

v 4 .

v 5 prp

v 6 vbp

v 7 [root]

v 8 ht

e 1 0 possession

e 3 1 direct

e 3 2 nominal

e 6 3 clausal

e 6 4 punctuation

e 6 5 nominal

e 7 6 root

e 7 8 root

e 8 8 null
```

Why it show this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MAX\Documents\success.py", line 18, in <module>
    extracted[L[2]] = node[L[2]]
KeyError: 'jj'
```

Comment: your code is trying to access an element which is not there node dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is a [KeyError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyError). The key 'jj' is not found in node as it is not present anywhere in file_1. You cannot call a value in a dictionary for which there is no key. If you want to ignore this error and add the key-value pair to both dictionaries, you need to [explicity handle for this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).